# Model update_attributes Not Updating a Value

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Rails 2.3.5

I have a form where there is a form field called 'MAX' and I'm including a 'MIN' parameter as a hidden field.   The MIN parameter is correctly included in the "threshold_control" param set.   But, for some reason Rails isn't including MIN in the update statement.   I don't see why at all, the MIN param is good and there in the form param set.

I guess I could do the update SQL manually.   Does anyone see why the MIN param is not being included in the update statement?  Thanks!

```
<% form_for(@threshold_control) do |f| %>
    <%= f.error_messages %>
    <%= hidden_field_tag(:min_max, 'same') %>
    <%= f.hidden_field :min, :value => @threshold_control.min %>


@threshold_control.update_attributes(params[:threshold_control])

Processing ThresholdControlsController#update (for 127.0.0.1 at 2011-12-21 11:59:50) [PUT]
  Parameters: {"commit"=>" Update ", "authenticity_token"=>"SZCCvAKRbHXEOhYp/+JcTJnMaI3YbxAP8LzwiqqfKbE=", "id"=>"71", "min_max"=>"same", "threshold_control"=>{"max"=>"12.1", "min"=>"12.0"}}
  ThresholdControl Columns (87.0ms)   SHOW FIELDS FROM `threshold_controls`
  ThresholdControl Load (1.0ms)   SELECT * FROM `threshold_controls` WHERE (`threshold_controls`.`id` = 71) 
  SQL (1.0ms)   BEGIN
  ThresholdControl Update (16.0ms)   UPDATE `threshold_controls` SET `max` = 12.1, `updated_at` = '2011-12-21 11:59:51' WHERE `id` = 71
  SQL (21.0ms)   COMMIT
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it is included in the params:

```
"threshold_control"=>{"max"=>"12.1", "min"=>"12.0"}
```

is min an actual column in the db? Have you run all the migrations? Do you have attr_protected (or attr_accessible) on *any* columns on this model?

Also, as an aside, if min is a db column - you won't need `:value=> @threshold_control.min` you should be able to just get away with:

```
<%= f.hidden_field :min %>
```

(even if you only set min on @threshold_value in the ruby action and it's not saved) 
If the above is not populating with the value of min... that would be useful to know too.

Comment: I figured out my stupidity.   In this case (an all or nothing threshold), the MIN and MAX value must be the same.  So, I'm just presenting the user with 1 text field for MAX value and then MIN value has to be a copy of it.   The field wasn't updating because it was the same as when the form opened.   In my controller I jest set the MIN param to = the MAX param before anything else happened.  Opps.  Long day.  Thanks.